# How to capture value OOPS & Generic

Tags: c#, oop, generics

here is my code given.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var _User = new User { Name="Test", Age=12 };
            _User.Save();
        }
    }

    public class DBObject<T>
    {
        public void Save()
        {

        }
    }

    public class User : DBObject<User>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

i want to capture user name & age from save method ? how could i do so......plzz guide. thanks

Comment: Plzz be more specific.

Comment: Do you want to implement your own `Save()` within `User` or access the `Save()` from `DBObject` (in which case I see no problem with your current code)

Comment: i want to write save logic in my DB related classes DBObject and allow other to extend DBObject and but when other class will invoke save() function then instance value will be passed to save() function of DBObject. so guide me how could i do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking at your code, why would one want to read class specific properties in a generic method?

The only solutions i see is to use Reflection, or create an abstract base class with a before save method and call that method in de Save() method. Add a generic type constraint to the DBObject class defining that T is of the basetype. This way you can add class specific functionality to a generic method.  Something like this:

```
public abstract class Base
{
     public virtual void BeforeSave()
     {

     }

}

public class User : Base
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }      

     public override void BeforeSave()
     {
          // You can access your properties here
          if (this.Name.Trim() == "")
              throw new Exception("Name is mandatory!")
     }

}

public class DBObject<T>
    where T: Base
{
    public void Save()
    {
        T.BeforeSave();
    }
}
```

Comment: whatever u said then please write a code which can help me to visualize what u r saying...thanks

Comment: just go to this url and tell me how they are doing http://dbentry.codeplex.com/

Comment: Edited my answer. Why do you want to read out those properties? For validation purposes?

Comment: i want to capture those value at Save() function level because i want to write a routine which will save data to db. so guide me how can i get user name & age from Save function of DBObject ??

Comment: Well, take a look at Entity Framework.. It does all of that for you..

Comment: what i need to look into Entity Framework. just give me the url and position too for look for :)

Comment: Go figure it out yourself. It doesn't look like you've even tried. There is not one link to all of EF.. It's an ORM Framework for all data transactions from and to the database. It converts db-tables to c# entity classes, or the other way around. If you realy want to generalize your db-transactions, don't reinvent the wheel and use EF.